# Is there something in between external and shared storage?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, router, hybrid-storage, local-storage

On a computer setup I'm aiming to achieve 2 things:

1. I want high speed external storage for my main PC. USB 3.0 fits well.
2. Also be able to share that storage with other devices. LAN speeds would be fine.

I've come up with several approaches like:

- PC as 24/7 server: Fulfills both, could even work with an internal HDD, but It's not energy efficient.
- Network drive & Router: Fulfills second, but can only output at Gigabit Ethernet speeds to my main PC.
- Regular USB 3.0 HDD & USB 3.0 capable router: Seemingly, fulfills second, but can only output at Gigabit Ethernet speeds to my main PC.

Do you have any other idea?

I don't understand why routers do not output anything above Gigabit ethernet.

Comment: Routers do, you're just looking at the wrong types of routers, though 10Gb routers are not cheap, and neither are the cables or the NICs necessary to utilize them. Why do you need more than 1Gb pipe on a LAN anyway? I work with a lot of companies in big data production environments that do just fine with 1G backbones.

Comment: I wouldn't put it in terms of **greater than gigabit ethernet**, but rather I just wanted to replicate what you get with regular external USB 3.0 HDD setups. Which is what you have before going **shared**

Comment: Look at synology NAS products. You can do link aggregation on them if you want to setup your network that way, which would provide you much faster access to the storage array. http://www.synology.com/support/tutorials_show.php?lang=us&q_id=525

Answer (score 0):

The last option you did not mention and it fits your needs perfectly! Get a external drive that has *both a network port and a USB 3.0 port on it*.

Just some quick googling I found [this by Corasair](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822233004), it has USB 3.0, Ethernet, even it's own WiFi access point built in (I am not recommending this product, I just wanted to show you they exist).

Make sure before you buy any drive that the drive supports accessing from both ports at the same time, some of the cheaper drives only allow one or the other to be connected at once.

Comment: Well I did think on dual ports possibilty. But apparently is not yet possible. To begin with there aren't many, and for instance, the ports on that one you mention do not work at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

**The fastest, cheapest, simplest thing you can do is put an internal drive in your PC and serve it up 24/7.**  Next up, the external USB drive; it is slower, less reliable, and cost more than an internal drive, but its still inexpensive, simple, and fast.

After that would be some sort of NAS.  But I personally would take the extra money from a NAS and invest it in more drives for back up and redundancy and upgrade my network to make sure everything is gigabit..

And don't forget about how you will deal with failures.  Internal and USB drives are readily available; NAS components are not as easy to source or could be more picky about hardware, while some network drive and router would definitely leave you limited on your options in the event of a failure.

As a note, a platter style drive will not typically saturate gigabit Ethernet at 125MB/s, and if your internet can, I wanna know who your provider is.  Plus, like others have said, use link aggregation from your PC to your router (if you can get a router that supports it) to up the available bandwidth.

Also, an idling computer will only cost about $60/year per $0.10/KWH @ 70 watts idling (many are less these days)  And since you'll have it on during the day anyways probably, that means you might be able to save a maximum of $20 a year or so (per $0.10/KWH)

A network drive and router will limit your options and scalability compared to your PC.  Maybe you'll want to add a back up drive.  Maybe you'll want to add another drive and setup a RAID 1 for redundancy.  Who knows.  Fact is a PC is pretty open on options, a network router and drive will be very limited on what they can do.

Comment: I disagree about scalability. Internal drives are not nearly as scalable as many NAS solutions (ie synology or glusterfs) and routers such as mikrotik, cisco and samsung are very customizable (as well as software options such as dd-wrt and tomato). The main issue with internal drives is the work necessary to either upgrade the drive or to create a RAID after the drive has been operating as a single disk for any amount of time can be tedious. You also often have limited number of slots for drives which compounds the issue.

Comment: 5 bay synology for $729 w no drives?  http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=854907&is=REG&A=details&Q=  You and I are in different worlds.  I would never think to spend that much on something like that.  $800 (you need at least one drive right?) would give me an enterprise card (150+/- used) with multiple large drives ($400+/-) for redundancy and a hot swap spare and a drive bay (90$ +/-) AND UPS for power failures.  You are right though, many people would never deal with that, even if they do post on a site called "super user".  Love the different perspective!

Comment: That is actually VERY cheap for storage. The storage appliances I deal with on a daily basis for work are $50k+ per unit and they contain redundant power, redundancy on drives and units (up to 4 complete units of 36 drives each can be lost and rebuilt) and the units will self-repair the data on the drives as well as perform self-checks for data-corruption, so I do suppose my perspective is quite different than most when it comes to storage.